# infowindow opens at same marker!

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

ok well , i have this code which is called for every position i fetch from a DB, the thing is that whenever i click on a marker the infowindow is shown with the respective marker information , but the position of the infowindow is always avobe the last marker added , in a nut shell info is fine but its not showed where it should be.

these two are declared when the map its initialized and are global.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var geocoder=new google.maps.Geocoder
```

this is the script

```
function addRoleMarker(lat,lng,rumbo,codigo,velocidad,nE,referer,utc,fecha)
{
 var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var title='No.'+nE+' '+utc;

baseMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
    title: title,
    zIndex: 1
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(baseMarker,'click',function(){
            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': myLatLng}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                switch(rumbo)
                {
                case 0:
                rumbo='N';
                break;  
                case 1:
                rumbo='NE';
                break;
                case 2:
                rumbo='E';
                break;
                case 3:
                rumbo='SE';
                break;
                case 4:
                rumbo='S';
                break;
                case 5:
                rumbo='SO';
                break;
                case 6: 
                rumbo='O';
                break;
                case 7:
                rumbo='NO';
                break;
                }

            var tablaR="<table><tr><td>Fecha:</td></tr><td>"+fecha;
            tablaR+="</td><tr><td>Fecha UTC:</td></tr><td>"+utc;
            tablaR+="</td><tr><td>Velocidad:</td></tr><td>"+velocidad;
            tablaR+="</td><tr><td>Rumbo:</td></tr><td>"+rumbo;
            tablaR+="</td><tr><td>Direccion:</td></tr><td>"+results[0].formatted_address;
            infowindow.setContent(tablaR);
            infowindow.open(map,baseMarker);
                }else{
                  alert("No results found");
                }
            }else{
                alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
              }});});
}
```

the number of markers depends on the data fetched acording to a sql query this is the php script

```
<?
$script="<script type='text/javascript'>";

    for($i=0;$i<count($losDatos);$i++)
    {
    $script.="addRoleMarker(".$losDatos[$i]['latitud'].",".$losDatos[$i]['longitud'].",".$losDatos[$i]['rumbo'].",".$losDatos[$i]['codigo'].",".$losDatos[$i]['velocidad'].",".$losDatos[$i]['numeroEconomico'].",1,'".$losDatos[$i]['utcDate']."','".$losDatos[$i]['localDate']."');";
    }

$script.='</script>';
echo $script;
?>
```

Comment: sounds like you have a typical google-map scope issue.  how many markers are on the map, and can you show us the entire code prefer with example data input so we can help narrow down the issue for you.

Comment: markers depend on the data fetched from a sql query! from 1 up to 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to see whole code to make suggestions but it seems you only add listener to one "baseMarker". So your infoWindow.open(map, baseMarker) opens at the same marker. I think you need to add listener to every marker you create.

Comment: full code ready , i think the same , but whenever i call the funcion i create a diferent HTML table , and the TABLE is showing the right information for every marker but the infowindow is always in above the last marker therefore the listener is ok. right?

Comment: So the behaviour you have now is that you can see all the markers but when you click on any of the marker, you see the information about the marker clicked but the infowindow is shown on a particular marker?

Comment: yes, i see all markers at their correct locations and each infowindow is set with the correct information but not placed to the correct marker

Comment: Oh I think I know why. You declared baseMarker without "var". This means the baseMarker becomes global variable in javascript. Please try declaring baseMarker with var.

Comment: It depends on why you want to keep the baseMarker for. One thing you can do is to create array of markers outside the function and pass it to the addRoleMarker function.

Or inside the function, declare the marker with "var" then make that function return the marker. Then you will have access to marker outside.

You should generally avoid declaring global variable like that as this is considered as bad programming practice.